# Disabling JIRA notification emails for REST API updates

Tags: rest, email, jira, jira-rest-api

I need to perform relatively frequent bulk updates/imports using the JIRA REST API.

This has been greatly increasing productivity but also causing immense amounts of spam.

Is there any way to disable notifications for emails made through the API or to enable/disable notifications globally through the API?

I'm using Atlassian OnDemand (version 5.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update - Jan 12 '17**

Can be done using the `PUT /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}` API [[specs](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-editIssue)].

[Added in JIRA Server 7.2](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-34423)

**Original post - Oct 23 '12**

As far as I know there isn't any way to do so using the REST API, and no built-in way to stop email notification for REST based updates (you can set notifications for specific set of actions). You could change the permissions using the SOAP API (check out [RemotePermissionScheme](http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/beans/RemotePermissionScheme.html) and [RemotePermissionMapping](http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/beans/RemotePermissionMapping.html)).

If this is not the solution that you were looking for, there might be some sort of a workaround. What are you updating? which fields?

For example, one possible solution would be to replace Jira's notification with your own notifications.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're suggesting using permissions to disable email notifications, performing the updates, then re-establishing the original permission scheme?

As far as use goes, I'm generally updating the time estimates, title, description, or a few different custom fields.

Comment: This is not possible currently, feel free to send your votes or comments to https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-34423

Comment: `/rest/api/2/issue/bulk?notifyUsers=false` doesn't work, users still get notified :(

Comment: @david

You may need ProjectAdmin or Admin rights:

    notifyUsers
    boolean

    Sends the notification email on issue update to all watchers. Admin or project admin permissions are required to disable the notification.

    Default: true

Comment: Yeah I keep reading that everywhere. However, I am project admin, and yet the notifications are sent.

Comment: any leads I also face the same issue, in a comment, assignee call "?notifyUsers=false" still sends a notification.